# Running the linux kernel and ubuntu on a custom processor

Tags: fpga, computer-architecture, alu

This is hardly a theoretical question as many have done this, albeit there's very little information on the underlying processes.

I'm developing a custom MIPS-based processor on which I would like to run ubuntu. I'm quite baffled as to what to do next after you've designed the instruction set and the computer architecture itself. I need to be able to run a kernel and OS but how does it all tie in? 
At the moment I'm researching into designing a compiler for the linux kernel to generate the appropriate assembly language. Is that a good way to go? What do I need to do after that?

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design!

Comment: This is way too broad for the Q+A format here.  It is not clear what specifically you are asking about.

Comment: Electronics is a remarkably broad term for quite a range of fields including computer architecture, computation, machine learning, digital engineering, human computer interaction, and so on. It isn't wrong thinking to post a question related to the straddling of a _custom processor_(the design of which belongs to the field of electronics) with software(note this requires knowledge of both the hardware design and software) and seeking an explanation of the layers between them. If you regard the question itself as broad, kindly request clarification from me, or perhaps provide a general answer.

Comment: Did you include an mmu in your design?

Comment: Yes, it does have an MMU.

Comment: Complete troll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, to program it satisfactorily, you will need a compiler. One way to get one is to adapt a code-generator back-end for GCC.

But then you need at least a bare bones runtime system. Here's a page on starting to develop one, using GCC as the compiler.

http://wiki.osdev.org/Ada_Bare_bones

Comment: Cheers for the link, @Brian%Drummond